# How to see the protractor e2e results in an html with screenshot of failed tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Instead of seeing the results in command line, I want to see all the protractor E2E results in an HTML with each failed test cases having an option to see the screenshot.

This is how we can see in a selenium test, right. Is there any grunt tasks doing the same?

Comment: Does [protractor-screenshot-reporter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-screenshot-reporter) fit your need?

Comment: I was looking on the same plugin. It is giving as json and screenshot, which is good. I just need an HTML format also. But, if nothing is available, I think, I can parse these JSON to an HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an HTML parser on top of protractor-screenshot-reporter. This will generate HTML reporter with links to screenshots. Hope someone finds this helpful.

[npmjs.org/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](http://npmjs.org/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter)

Answer (score 0):

For protractor running Jasmine 2.x:
https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter